# While Loops in C++ without braces and a function call in parenthesis?

Tags: c++, while-loop

In C++ a while statement like this...

```
while (currGame.playGame(currPlayer) == true);
```

is perfectly legal as long as the playGame function returns true or false but is this considered **ugly** code?

Comment: The ugliest part is the `== true`. If it's a condition, treat it as one.

Comment: A condition can only be `true` or `false`; explicitly comparing it to a boolean value when you already have its value is redundant and wasteful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not pretty. If a null statement is used as the loop body, it's better to make it explicit:

```
while (currGame.playGame(currPlayer))
    ;  // do nothing
```

Or, better:

```
while (currGame.playGame(currPlayer)) {
}
```

I've also removed `== true` part as it's not a good coding style, either.

Comment: Or just `while (currGame.playGame(currPlayer)) { }`, no need to make the empty `;` explicit.

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified to

```
while (currGame.playGame(currPlayer));
```

This kind of while loops is rare. It is usually in a form like this:

```
while (currGame.hasNext())
{
    currGame.playGame(currPlayer);
}
```

Comment: I don't often see .hasNext() in C++ code - mostly that's a Java thing isn't it?

Comment: Sure, in C++ it is more like `while(!currGame.empty())` of simply `while(currGame)`. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Ugly or pretty depend on you!** But keep in mind

- Programs should be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.
- Make it clearer to both humans and compilers that the code does 
  what you intended.

As Other answers I would shorten your code to 
`while (currGame.playGame(currPlayer));`. But anyway this is not a big deal.

For further this small book would be a good reference to read [http://www.amazon.com/Coding-Standards-Rules-Guidelines-Practices/dp/0321113586](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586)

Comment: You are not actually shortening anything, did you forget to remove the `== true` part?

Answer (score -1):

```
while (currGame.playGame(currPlayer) == true);
```

is perfectly legal but is less readable. A more explicit way of doing the same is :

```
while (currGame.playGame(currPlayer))
;; // do nothing
/* A single semicolon is just fine as mentioned by @yu-hao
 * but a lot of C/C++ libraries use ;; for an empty statement.
 */
```

or

```
 while (currGame.playGame(currPlayer)){
    ;; // do nothing
 }
```

**Why should you avoid `while(condition);`**

In the below example :

```
while(true) // suppose you missed a semicolon here
return 0; // Instead of expected infinite loop, your program exits.
```

**Notes**

Avoid **== true** stuff because it can easily be **mistakenly** typed as **= true** - say you had a key-jump - and if that is the case, you have a bug which is difficult to catch.